# Scope Issue in Cloudinary multiple Upload

Tags: node.js, upload, cloudinary

I have this route that upload multiple files to cloudinary if I console.log (assetUpload) array within the upload loop it shows the url of uploaded pictures. But when I send the urls as response back to client the array is empty. I think this is some sort of scope issue.

```
router.route('/update/')
  .post(
    multiUpload
    ,
    async(req, res)=> {
    try {
      // console.log(req.body);
      var assetUploaded = [];
      let {signature, companyLogo, profilePicture} = req.files;
      let assets = [signature, companyLogo,profilePicture ];
      // console.log(assets[0])
      await assets.forEach ((asset) => {
        cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
          asset[0].path, (error, result) => {
            error ? res.status(400).json({message :error.message}) :
            // assetUploaded.push(result.secure_url)
            assetUploaded.push(
              {
              name:asset[0].fieldname,
              url: result.secure_url
            }
            )
            console.log(assetUploaded)
          }
        )
      })
      res.status(200).json({
        message : `user updated successfully`,
        urls : assetUploaded
    })
    } catch (err) {
      // console.log(err)
      res.status(400).json({message: 'Error occured ' +err.message})
    }
  })
```